# Induction and Integration by Parts

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $T: C([0,2]) \to C([0,2])$ be given by
>   $(Tf)(x) = \int_0 ^x f(t)dt$ Prove $$(T^n f)(x) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0 ^x (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am attempting this with induction and integration by parts. However,  I am struggling with the induction step to show the $(n+1)$ case holds. No matter what substitution I use for $u$ and $dv$, I am unable to proceed. (I first tried $u = (x-t)^n$ to use the induction hypothesis, but did not succeed.)  Any ideas on how to proceed/conclude?

Comment: Assuming the hypothesis for $n, (n-1)! (T^{n+1} f) (x)= \int_{0}^x \left(\int_0^t (x - s)^{n-1} f(s) \,\mathrm{d}s\right) \,\mathrm{d}t.$ Now apply Fubini's theorem to exchange the order of the $s$ and $t$ integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(T^{2}f)(x)&=\int_{0}^{x}(Tf)(t)dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{t}f(u)dudt\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}\chi_{[0,t]}(u)f(u)dudt\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}\chi_{[u,x]}(t)dtf(u)du\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}(x-u)f(u)du.
\end{align*}
Similarly, we have 
\begin{align*}
(T^{n+1}f)(x)&=\int_{0}^{x}(T^{n}f)(t)dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{t}(t-u)^{n-1}f(u)dudt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}\chi_{[u,x]}(t)(t-u)^{n-1}dtf(u)du\\
&=\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{u}^{x}(t-u)^{n-1}dtf(u)du\\
&=\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\dfrac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{x}(x-u)^{n}f(u)du\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{x}(x-u)^{n}f(u)du.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Given, $T(f)(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$

Induction hypothesis: The result holds for n.

Let, $T(f)(x)=g(x)$ then $g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)=f(x)$

Now,

$T^{n+1}(f(x))=T^n(T(f(x)))=T^n(g(x))$

$=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^{n-1}g(t)dt$

$=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}[[-g(t)\frac{(x-t)^n}{n}]_{0}^{x}+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{n}(x-t)^ng'(t)dt]$

$=\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^x(x-t)^nf(t)dt$

Hope this works.